# StructField issue at compilation when specifying table schema

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to specify a schema for a table I do it in JAVA using the following code :

```
StructType schema =  new StructType(List
                (
                        StructField("id", NumericType,  true),
                        StructField("text", StringType,  true),
                        StructField("user", StringType,  true)
                ));
```

BUT `NumericType`, `StringType` give error saying "expecting expression".
How to solve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains some mistakes. You need to use `new` keyword to create `StructField` and you cannot use `List(StructField, ...)`. Also, there is no `NumericType` in spark sql types, you probably want to use `IntegerType`. See available [Spark DataTypes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html).

That said, you can try with this :

```
StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[]{
                new StructField("id", IntegerType, true, null),
                new StructField("text", StringType, true, null),
                new StructField("user", StringType, true, null)
        });
```

Or using static import with the provided methods from `DataTypes` factory:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes.*;

StructType schema = createStructType(Arrays.asList(
                createStructField("id", IntegerType, true),
                createStructField("text", StringType, true),
                createStructField("user", StringType, true)
        ));
```

Comment: Alright for `DataTypes` i was checking this link : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DataType.html
Could you provide Spark Reference for the code you provided ? Thanks !

Comment: @marcnicole you can find many references in the [provided java spark examples](https://github.com/apache/spark/search?l=Java&p=3&q=new+StructField)